# Python thinks I don't have TensorFlow and PyTorch installed

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, package, torch

I am trying to use Python's transformers, however, I get the following error message:

> RuntimeError: At least one of TensorFlow 2.0 or PyTorch should be installed. To install TensorFlow 2.0, read the instructions at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/ To install PyTorch, read the instructions at https://pytorch.org/.

I have just installed them with pip, and I can't figure out what the problem is.

I tried looking at the .**version** for torch, tensorflow and transformers, and I have the versions 2.0.1+cpu for torch; 2.12.0 for tensorflow and 4.29.2

Still, even after reinstalling everything, I got the same messages.

Comment: How do you install them and how do you run your script? They might be installed in a different python environment

Answer (score 2):

if you have more than one version of python, in windows check with below command in cmd prompt.

`where python*`

try installing the same packages with pip3 if you are sure that you have only one python3 version. **Or follow the below for definitely working case**
Note: This is a generally preferred steps for any python project

1. Install venv
2. Create a virtual environment in the same repo as the project using
   `py -m venv venv`
3. Activate the virtual environment
   `./venv/Scripts/activate.bat`
4. pip install the required components
   This way reads the package from venv, so you can be sure where the packages are involved.

Do upvote if you find this useful